# How to resolve SQL Server installation error: 1722?

Tags: sql-server, installation

My DBA team is facing issues lately with installing SQL Server on VMs.

Every time the first attempt fails with: "Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor." Each time they run the installer again, the installation succeeds eventually on the second try.

According to the install summary, the failing components are the engine and the full text service. The dependent service that causes the error is the Shared Features. If I go to the Shared Features log, it says that the problematic service is the AzureAttestService. And indeed, even after the successful installation, the AzureAttestService is stopped, and timeouts when I try to start it.

First I found the following MS article, but it's not helpful, as it happens with SQL 2022 as well: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb4530084-fix-error-occurs-when-you-try-to-install-sql-server-2019-on-a-low-power-cpu-f2ab38f7-1def-c6a3-790e-bfff86f89820

This guy had the exact same issue but could not come to a permanent fix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/986583/micosoft-sql-server-2019-standard-azureattestservi

Did anyone face the same issue and managed to resolve it? Any kind of advice is more than welcome!

Comment: Did you try installing as an admin?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server? Do you need the Full Text Search feature?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realized I didn't run as administrator.
Reboot the server, and rerun as administrator, the issue has gone!